# Bokeh plots are very difficult to load

Tags: javascript, python, python-3.x, bokeh

I am trying to show a Bokeh plot in Firefox. There are quite many sub-graphs (approximately 200), each showing 1-4 objects.

I am receiving in Firefox:

```
"A webpage is slowing down your browser."
```

Some notes:

- After rebooting, it works fine for a couple of times.
- I am behind a corporate proxy. I ask myself if it may be the cause. Some JavaScript and CSS is being loaded from cnb.pydata.com.

Comment: Are you the one in control of the 200 plots or is an "external" resource?

Comment: It is a local HTML, fully generated by me.

Comment: Then my suggestion is to avoid having 200 Bokeh graphs in one single page.

Comment: Speaking as the project lead for Bokeh, if you need to display 200 plots on a single page, Bokeh is not the appropriate tool for your use case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like your Firefox version is having issues with said webpage. Although I'd say that the design of such site trying to show 200 JS driven plots seems questionable.

As far as I know, there is little that you can do besides updating Firefox, they have been busy lately improving many elements of performance, or trying another browser with better JS performance like Chrome.

If you're in a corporate network it might be many not possible for you to upgrade or install, then you have to go to you IT department looking for help.

Now, since you're generating the HTML with the graphs, perhaps would it be a better idea for you to make a "dashboard" where you show a few and then use dropdown menus or sliders to control which plots are shown at any given time. I've seen solutions using using bokeh itself to do so, or if you want eventually somethign fancier you can also use flask.